# Can we post questions that seek analysis for our own games?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I recently played a game and I was looking for some human analysis on it.  I thought I played very well despite my opponents higher rating.  There were things in the game that I did differently than I normally would and I was wondering if what I did had a name to it, but I am not sure if it is appropriate to post it as a question that probably could be a wiki?

Personally, I think these make great questions because chess is a lot about analysis and players love to analyze other peoples games and you can actually get answers to a lot of other questions when analysis is done, plus you get the added benefit of improving. I think this would drive more traffic to our site as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So long as the position/game isn't boring or too simplistic, I think it's a great idea.  While the specific game will be very localized, some of the themes will hopefully be useful and interesting.

In a game that's decided by a horrific blunder early on in the game, the computer is probably a better source for ideas and guidance.  In a game that's decided based on themes or more abstract ideas, then the game is probably a better fit for this site.

Put another way, if you are embarrassed to show the game because one or both players played poorly, it's probably better to not post the game - maybe try [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3293/chess) instead.  If the game had no overt blunders, post away!

Comment: +1 Good point about "themes or more abstract ideas".  Otherwise, it will certainly be too localized.

Comment: If we do post a game, should we tag it as analysis or something else or a combination of tags?

Comment: @xaisoft probably include the [tag:analysis] tag, but anything else you think of for the specific position should be fine.